# Learn MVC in a new project, or stick with WebForms?

Tags: .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, webforms

I'm a front-end guy who's picked up ASP.NET WebForms through working on various projects at my agency.

I have a project with a developer in mind, and I want to use/learn MVC for it - but he thinks it not worth using MVC at all. His opinion is that the benefits of MVC are perceived, and that performance won't be an issue, and it better to just push forward with WebForms.

The project is a web app that will give people project planning tools, creation of a personal contact database, and their own basic website.

My personal feelings are that I hate all the bloat that comes with WebForms sites - the ViewState, the one , the enormous JS files, the lack of control of markup (e.g. validation controls).

Obviously, ASP.NET WebForms is linked to resources, but MVC is about URL structures and interpreting them.

After discussion and research I'm thinking now that because of the supposedly large transition/learning curve of MVC, it really is better to just stay with WebForms.

I watched Ryan Singer work with RoR MVC in person, and I was stunned at how rapid everything was to develop.

Should I just accept that it's more pragmatic and productive to keep with WebForms now, and not use MVC, or should I find a way of convincing my co-worker that MVC is the right thing to do?

Comment: Apologies, Ian, for the poor and inconsistent grammar. I was in a rush to post before entering a meeting. Thanks for editing, although a little pedantic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would strongly recommend the ASP.NET MVC front - maybe it takes some time to get into it! But it's certainly been that. If, for example, back to change anything in retrospect, it is much more flexible and easier.

I would use this with LINQ, for example if you are using a database.

ASP.NET MVC may seem very difficult at first, but once you get into it you can make projects far more quickly. It is certainly my opinion.

Another good thing is that we have built good support for [Test Driven Development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development).

---

**Edit** *(added explanation)*:

One reason is that MVC is built up is 3 parts Model, View and Controller. This means you can share the logic from the markup in a good way. I will not go into details of how MVC is built here, since this is a chapter of its own! ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controlle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93View%E2%80%93Controller)r)

And as I mentioned above then you have very good support for TDD, which I personally do that I could use this only for this reason. URL Routing in ASP.NET MVC is also quite fanatical, which I have missed good support in ASP.NET.
ScottGu has written a really good blog about just this:
http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/12/03/asp-net-mvc-framework-part-2-url-routing.aspx

Comment: So the point you are making is, it's easier to maintain than a web forms project? Could you explain why you think this?

Answer (score 4):

MVC is a large learning curve because it's very different from web forms. If you are doing this project with someone else who doesn't want to learn MVC, then you may as well stick with web forms. You can't teach someone who doesn't want to learn, so you'll basically be spinning your wheels fruitlessly, and you already have a background in web forms so you'll at least be comfortable and familiar with the environment enough to make progress.

If you're doing this on your own or with a team that is willing to learn MVC, then I would recommend going that route less for the performance and tool availability than for learning something new and moving towards a framework that is largely built on the concept of test-driven development.

Asp.Net MVC is a very different framework, and it has definite advantages, but you'll also be dealing with the disadvantage of inexperience, so you'll need to have a project you can take your time with because you'll undoubtedly have to restart certain things a few times before you get things how you want them to be. You'll start, learn something new that makes you go back to square one, learn something new that makes you go back to square one, lather, rinse, repeat.

Comment: This is where I am at now. My question is, overall - is this worth doing now, at the start of a project.

Comment: @user315412 - If you can devote the time to learning it and have the patience to be able to stop/restart from scratch after learning something groundbreaking, then I would say yes. MVC seems to me to be better for larger projects, but even a small project is decent as a learner.

Answer (score 0):

It is probably worth learning MVC just for the sake of education. It gives benefits to the front end dev for sure but there are downsides for the backend guys. However for a small project with normal amount of client-side work it is probably the same so you can use the project to learn a new technology. BTW I too prefer Web Forms as it is a higher level of abstraction.

Usually you should choose ASP.NET MVC when you have AJAX heavy frontend with a lot of animations and visual effects where the control over the markup is important. You should choose Web Forms if you have a lot of data input and widget style independent controls that you reuse a lot because you can encapsulate the behaviour a lot better.

Comment: "downsides for the backend guys" -> how so?  I find it far similar front to back.

Comment: @Stilgar - I don't see downsides for backend guys. Given LINQ to SQL and the usage of the strongly-typed model I find it almost ideal as a "backend guy". If you think web forms has a "higher level of abstraction" then I don't think you've taken the time to learn MVC. I find MVC has a far higher level of abstraction than web forms, and I've only just broken the surface (I'm a web forms developer mid-transition).

Comment: @Joel components can hide implementation details like the HTML needed to render a control or turning an HTTP POST to a .NET event. Therefore Components are higher level of abstraction. With Web Forms you can develop a web site with almost no knowledge of HTML. It won't be the best markup ever created but you can do that.

Comment: @Fermin I find the inability to encapsulate presentation markup and presentation logic in a control inconvenient. Also with MVC you have to take care of many additional security considerations. For example if you have a delete button and hide it for non admin users this is enough for Web Forms, but with MVC you need to remember to check again in the action if the user has the right to delete.

Comment: @Stilgar - html isn't a hidden implementation detail. The code that renders the html might be a hidden implementation detail, but that's a detail of the controls provided. MVC has the same controls, it just doesn't require the same garbage during the render. They're just as abstract, and they also expect that the data used is abstracted into your own business/data layers. Web forms doesn't expect this abstraction in your own code, and often its methods are a hinderance to that abstraction layer. I disagree with your description of abstraction, and consider MVC to be much more abstract.

Comment: What garbage are you refering to?
What is more Web Forms has exactly the same expectations about the underlying model as MVC. If you disagree please point out to a specific model technique that can be used with Web Forms but cannot be used with MVC.
Even if the code that renders HTML is implementation details that does not change the fact that you can hide it in Web Forms but not in MVC unless you use RenderAction which is just a fancy way to work around the MVC patter by making the view aware of the existance of the Action (i.e. the same as with Web Forms)

Answer (score 0):

There're 100 reasons to choose MVC, or Web Forms. But given that you're a front-end developer, the learning curve for you is not as much as back-end developers, who usually have very little idea on coding HTML.

Your existing skills like JS, CSS and Html will be seamlessly ported to MVC.